# Reporting Services, getting error during the arithmetic operation

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to get a difference between two dates in SQL Server Reporting Services. I have leaving date, and next arrive date. I'm using two iif's to count days in first, and hours, minutes, and seconds in second iif.

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value)=False,

Floor(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value, Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value) / 86400)

& iif(Floor((DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value, Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value)) / 86400)=1," day ", " days ") & 

Format(DateAdd("s", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value, Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")

, "No data")
```

And the problem is, after calculating, when there is no data for Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value, I'm getting error with: `Expression The hidden value in the text "Textbox20.Paragraphs [0] .TextRuns [0]" contains an error: An overflow occurred during the arithmetic operation.`

Comment: Some sample data for which the error occurs could help

Comment: When `Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value1  is 2018-06-08 10:34:15 and `Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value` is 2018-06-09 20:35:43 everything is calculated properly. But when `Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value` is 2018-06-09 22:35:44 and `Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value` is NULL I'm receiving error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with you expression part

```
DateAdd("s", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value, Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value), "00:00:00")
```

Iif evaluates all the expressions, even when conditions are false

You need and extra Iif to always return a valid value for Dateadd

```
   DateAdd("s", Iif(IsNothing(Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value)=False,DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value, Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value),0)
```

Below is the full expression

```
= iif(IsNothing(Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value)=False,

Floor(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value, Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value) / 86400)

& iif(Floor((DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value, Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value)) / 86400)=1," day ", " days ") & 

Format(DateAdd("s", Iif(IsNothing(Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value)=False,DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!LeaveDateTimeUtc.Value, Fields!NextEnterDateTimeUtc.Value),0), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")

, "No data")
```